# Closed subspace of ${\rm L}^{2}[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

$\textbf{My exercise says:}$ : For each $0 \leq a \leq1$ let $$M_{a}=\{ f \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]:f(x)=0, \hspace{0.3 ex} \text{ to Lebesgue almost every point} \ x  \in [0,a]\}$$

i) $M_{a}$ closed subspace of ${\rm L}^{2}[0,1]$

My attempt was:
Let $\textbf{1} \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]$ be the function $\textbf{1}(t)=1$  $\forall t \in [0,a]$, define the map $T: {\rm L}^{2}[0,1] \to \mathbb C$
$$x \to \langle \textbf{1},x\rangle$$
i) T is linear. ok  
ii) T is continuous

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
 |Tx| =  \left|\int_{0}^{1}\textbf{1}(t) x(t)dt\right| &\leq \int_{0}^{1}|\textbf{1}(t)| |x(t)|dt\\
 &\leq \left(\int_{0}^{a} 1 dt\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_{0}^{a} x(t)dt\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \sqrt{a} ||x||
    \end{split}
 \end{equation}
Can I think like this?,
$T^{-1}(0)= \{x \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]: Tx = 0\} = \{x \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]: \int_{0}^{1}\textbf{1}(t) x(t)dt = 0\} = \{x \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]: \int_{0}^{a} x(t)dt = 0\} = M_{a}$

Then $M_{a}$ is closed.Thanks!

Comment: This is not working because your set $T^{-1}(0)$ is much larger than $M_a$.

Comment: For closedness use that convergence in $L^2$ implies pointwise a.e. convergence of a subsequence.

Comment: By reusing your idea, you could use the map $G \colon L^2[0,1] \to \mathbb R$, $f \mapsto \int_0^a |f(x)|^2 \mathrm{d}x$ or $F \colon L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,a]$, $f \mapsto f|_{[0,a]}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the map $G: {\rm L}^{2}[0,1] \to \mathbb R$
$$f \to \int_{0}^{a} |f(x)|^{2}dx$$
i) G is linear. ok  
ii) G is continuous

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
 |G(f)| =  \left|\int_{0}^{a} |f(x)|^{2} dx\right| &\leq \int_{0}^{a} |f(x)|^{2} dx\\
 & = \left(\int_{0}^{a} |f(x)|^{2} dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{0}^{a} |f(x)|^{2} dx\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq  2||f||
    \end{split}
 \end{equation}

$G^{-1}(0)= \{f \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]: Gf = 0\} = \{f \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]: \int_{0}^{a} |f(x)|^{2}dx = 0\} = \{f \in {\rm L}^{2}[0,1]: f(t)= 0,  \ 0\leq t\leq  a\}  = M_{a}$

Answer (score 0):

You could just argue that if we have a sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in $M_a$ such that $||f - f_n||_{L^2}$ for some $f$, then there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k \geq 1}$ such that $f_{n_k} \to f$ almost everywhere. Since $f_{n_k} = 0$ a.e. for all $k \geq 1$, then we must have $f=0$ a.e.. Thus, $f \in M_a$